# What is the basic POM.xml structure in plug in project in Java RCP

Tags: eclipse, maven, plugins, pom.xml, rcp

What is the basic POM.xml structure in plug in project in Java RCP.I have POM.xml content as below.With this content it is able to launch the product but maven build is not successful.If I remove   part its building but application is not able to launch.Its displaying the following error message:

org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The activator com.cerner.scrumdashboard.Activator for bundle com.cerner.scrumdashboard is invalid
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1207)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.cerner.scrumdashboard.Activator
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:164)
    ... 24 more
Root exception:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.cerner.scrumdashboard.Activator
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1207)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)

POM.xml content:
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    com.cerner.scrumdashboard
    com.cerner.scrumdashboard
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.18</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>



</dependencies>


<!-- <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\javac.exe</executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build> -->
```